# Refresh mat-table in angular 9

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular9

When I delete element my MAT-TABLE is not refresh

.ts file

```
import { MatTableDataSource, MatTable } from '@angular/material/table';
@ViewChild(MatTable) table: MatTable<any>;

const index = this.dataSource.data.findIndex(d => Number(d.id) == Number(id)); 
this.dataSource.data.splice(index, 1);
this.table.renderRows();
```

.html file

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="lessons-table mat-elevation-z8" matSort table>
```

Comment: Prefer immutable methods like `filter` and use `triple-equals`: `this.dataSource.data = this.dataSource.data.filter(item => +item.id !== +id);`. Doing that way, you don't need to use `findIndex`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the `mat-table` data to update, you need to immutably assign the new array to your `dataSource`.

Try this.

```js
this.dataSource.data = this.dataSource.data.splice(index, 1);
```